# Bar Code Scan event capture text

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a win forms app that i am trying to add a bar code scan too.

The window has multi able text boxes which the user fills in. When user clicks on a box and scans bar code it goes into the selected text box.

Is it possible to write an event to put the text into a particular textbox when scanned even if a different text box is highlighted?

If so how would i do this. 
Thanks

Comment: Since Winforms of .NET does not have any built in functionality to handle barcode scanning, this would probably need to be done with the library you use to do that. Since you have not told us which library you use to do that it will be impossible for anyone here to answer this question. Perhaps you could create a [mcve] and post the name / link to the library you're using so that we can see what you're dealing with?

Comment: Can you recommend any library's to use?

Comment: @inkey almost all barcode scanners (at least the ones that I have used) send the text in whats called 'keyboard wedge' mode. It sends all the keys to the highlighted field as if you were typing them on a keyboard.

Comment: No, sorry, for two reasons. 1. I haven't written any code for barcode scanning, and 2. recommendations are off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Bmo Thanks for valued feedback. I have this working when i click on textbox however when i dont have the box selected it doesnt insert into the textbox.This is where my issue is how do i read what has been scanned when no text box is selected.

Comment: As Bmo says bar-code readers often masquerade as the keyboard, which is why the scan ends up in the most recently clicked textbox. You could write a key event for the form (or something similar), but then you would need some method of identifying which scan should go where. Are the different scans identifiable from their format? Do you always scan in a fixed order?

Comment: @Graham Yes i will be able to identify it however how do i read the keyboard value in the key press event?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty on this, but there is a `KeyPreview` property for the form and a `PreviewKeyDown` event. I would google around that to start with.

Comment: @inkey It depends on the barcode. In manufacturing we use AIAG prefixes and the first letter of the scan denotes what field the data belongs to and can easily direct the input. If you're using UPC, EAN, 128 etc. you might have trouble. The other sticking point is that the computer cannot discern input coming from the keyboard and coming from the scanner. You can get into some formatting and other tweaks depending on your scanner but dedicating a field to scanning has always worked best.

Comment: Why can't / haven't you shared your code? You said you have it working for when you have a textbox selected, well, in what event are you capturing the barcode and passing its data to the textbox? Show us *how* you're doing it and maybe we can offer suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

There are different types of barcode scanners: keyboard wedge, and serial ones.

Keyboard wedge will send 'messages' as if they were input from the keyboard. So normally they only appear when some kind of edit box has focus.

To put that scanned data in a textbox without having focus, the best and safest way would be to capture the messages in a seperate background thread (this could work for KB wedge as wel as for serial). With KB wedge, your thread would have to check the (prefix)codes to see if they are coming from the barcode scanner - if not, forward then to the normal windows message processing.

Some barcode scanners might have libraries available that already do that for you.

On the other hand, if the app has only one window, and a KB wedge scanner is used, a seperate thread could be avoided, and the messages can be captured inside that window, analysed, and if a barcode is detected the data can be put in the right text box. But I would never trust the user to be in the right text box when scanning the barcode - in fact, that text box should better be read-only.

But, in general, when the application has multiple windows, a background thread may be the only option. Some examples:

- A user scans a barcode on a document (invoice for example), and that document needs to be opened automatically. The thread could capture the code, and open that document.
- A user scans an EAN code, and wants to see the details of the product. Same as above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example code that handles scan events. The scnner has to be configured as a serial scanner, they usually come with barcodes that configure the scanner.

```
private SerialPort InitializeScanner()
{
    SerialPort port = null;
    bool result;
    int iPort = 2;
    do
    {
        try
        {
            result = true;
            port = new SerialPort("COM" + iPort, 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            port.Close();
            if (!port.IsOpen)
                port.Open();
            port.DiscardOutBuffer();
            port.DiscardInBuffer();
            port.DataReceived += OnScan;
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            iPort++;
            result = false;
        }
    } while (result == false && iPort <= 20);

    return port;
}
```

It's all about this line:

```
port.DataReceived += OnScan;
```

Here's an example of OnScan. You can set any textbox in that function, although note that you have to use Invoke to set the GUI components, the serial port thread is a different thread from the GUI one.

```
private void OnScan(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    SerialPort port = sender as SerialPort;

    string line = port.ReadExisting();

    int idx = line.IndexOf('\r');
    if (idx != -1)
    {
        line = line.Substring(0, idx);
        _scanBuffer += line;
        Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { OnScan(_scanBuffer); });
        _scanBuffer = "";
    }
    else
    {
        _scanBuffer += line;
    }
}
```